# Shopify graph call returns lesser data than REST call

Tags: android, rest, graph, shopify

Shopify `REST` api returns 141 products in a collection. Shopify graph query returns 110 products in the same collection. Why is there a difference?

```
{

node(id:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"){__typename,... 
on Collection{id,products(first:30){edges{cursor,node{id,title,description,
descriptionHtml,productType,handle,tags,
images(first:10)
{edges{node{src,altText,id,originalSrc}}},
variants(first:10){edges{node{id,price,title,sku,availableForSale,
image{originalSrc,altText,id,src}}}}}}}}}}
```

This query returns 30+30+30+20 items in pagination. So i am getting only 110 items. But there are actually 141 items in the collection. Why is there a difference? Can anyone please explain?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Some things would be helpful to know here. 1) what was your RestAPI call? 2) was there any messaging or errors in the payload from GQL? GQL usually returns a productCount too in queries, what does it tell you? What was your exact query endpoint?

Comment: 1. ```/admin/api/2020-10/collections/{collection_id}.json``` is my RestAPI end point.
2. no errors or messaging in GQL. And GQL didn't return the product count in the response. Liquid api returns the product count in the collection. And also rest api returns product count in response

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple call and there is a productsCount. You should play with Insomnia to learn the schema and what you can and cannot do with your GQL:

```
collection(id: $id) {
      id
      title
      description
      productsCount
}
```

So with this, you can throw in the products too, I am just demo'ing that product count should match RestAPI without a doubt.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you get this? Can you update your answer with full query. 
And, there are no filters in my query (ignore the first=30). Then why is the collection size lesser than actual size?

Comment: Use Insomnia. It is a tool that lets you issue GQL queries against your store. It provides you with a view into the schema. Use the right tools for the job!